# Did Ibn Abbas RA say that only 4 types of food were prohibited and nothing else?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, fiqh, sahaba

In the book "The lawful and prohibited" by sheikh Yusuf al Qaradawi, he cites an opinion from Ibn Abbas that only 4 types of food are prohibited as mentioned in the verse "Say, "I do not find within that which was revealed to me [anything] forbidden to one who would eat it unless it be a dead animal or blood spilled out or the flesh of swine - for indeed, it is impure - or it be [that slaughtered in] disobedience, dedicated to other than Allah. But whoever is forced [by necessity], neither desiring [it] nor transgressing [its limit], then indeed, your Lord is Forgiving and Merciful."

According to Ibn 'Abbas, nothing is haram other than the four categories mentioned in the Qur'an, while what the Prophet (pbuh) forbade, such as beasts of prey, are to be regarded as makruh (detestable) rather than reaching the degree of haram. Said ibn 'Abbas,

"The people of the time of Jahiliyyah ate certain foods and avoided others, according to their whim. Then Allah sent His Prophet (pbuh) and revealed His Book, and He legislated what is permissible and what is prohibited. Accordingly, what He permitted is halal, what He prohibited is haram , and that concerning which He was silent is allowed.

Ibn 'Abbas then recited.

4 Say: I do not find in what is revealed to me anything prohibited to an

eater in his food...

(Al-An'am: 145) (2)

On the basis of this verse, Ibn 'Abbas argued that the flesh of domesticated donkeys is permissible. Imam Malik agrees with him on this matter, considering beasts of prey makruh rather than haram.
Reference: The lawful and prohibited page 51

The footnote on the bottom says this was a saying of Ibn Abbas recorded in Abu Dawud although the exact reference number was not given. Is this authentic and where can I find it?[image]

Comment: https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5529 , https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3800 , https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4227

Comment: Jazakhallah khairan